# Galaxy tab 3 is not showing al layouts correctly, Nexus 7 2nd generation is

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-tabhost

Somehow my Galaxy tab 3 is not showing all layouts correctly. This is the screenshot from the Galaxy tab:

[image: screenshot galaxy tab]

Here is how it should look and looks on the Nexus 7 (a different option is selected hence the different white button):

[image]

This is my FragmentTabHost layout:

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

This is the XML of a tab view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/tab_image"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tab_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the Java code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    //
    //more application logics here
    //

    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    werkplekIndicator = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_view, null);
    transportIndicator = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_view, null);
    inkomendIndicator = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_view, null);
    zoekenIndicator = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_view, null);
    planningIndicator = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_view, null);

    b.putString("key", "Werkplek");
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Werkplek")
            .setIndicator(werkplekIndicator), WerkplekFragment.class, b);
    b.putString("key", "Transport");
    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("Transport").setIndicator(transportIndicator),
            TransportFragment.class, b);
    b.putString("key", "Inkomend");
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Inkomend")
            .setIndicator(inkomendIndicator), InkomendFragment.class, b);
    b.putString("key", "Zoeken");
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Zoeken").setIndicator(zoekenIndicator),
            ZoekenFragment.class, b);
    b.putString("key", "Planning");
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Planning").setIndicator(planningIndicator),
            PlanningFragment.class, b);

    mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);

    setTabViews(); 
}

private void setTabViews() {
    TabWidget tabWidget = mTabHost.getTabWidget();
    tabWidget.setDividerDrawable(R.drawable.empty_divider);

    werkplekIndicator.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_3d_tab_first);
    TextView werkplekIndicatorTitle = (TextView) werkplekIndicator.findViewById(R.id.tab_label);
    werkplekIndicatorTitle.setText("Werkplek");
    werkplekIndicatorTitle.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    ImageView werkplekIndicatorIcon = (ImageView) werkplekIndicator.findViewById(R.id.tab_image);
    werkplekIndicatorIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_werkplek);

    transportIndicator.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_3d_tab_middle);
    TextView transportIndicatorTitle = (TextView) transportIndicator.findViewById(R.id.tab_label);
    transportIndicatorTitle.setText("Transport");
    transportIndicatorTitle.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    ImageView transportIndicatorIcon = (ImageView) transportIndicator.findViewById(R.id.tab_image);
    transportIndicatorIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_transport);

    inkomendIndicator.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_3d_tab_middle);
    TextView inkomendIndicatorTitle = (TextView) inkomendIndicator.findViewById(R.id.tab_label);
    inkomendIndicatorTitle.setText("Inkomend");
    inkomendIndicatorTitle.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    ImageView inkomendIndicatorIcon = (ImageView) inkomendIndicator.findViewById(R.id.tab_image);
    inkomendIndicatorIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_inkomend);

    zoekenIndicator.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_3d_tab_middle);
    TextView zoekenIndicatorTitle = (TextView) zoekenIndicator.findViewById(R.id.tab_label);
    zoekenIndicatorTitle.setText("Zoeken");
    zoekenIndicatorTitle.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    ImageView zoekenIndicatorIcon = (ImageView) zoekenIndicator.findViewById(R.id.tab_image);
    zoekenIndicatorIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_zoeken);

    planningIndicator.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_3d_tab_last);
    TextView planningIndicatorTitle = (TextView) planningIndicator.findViewById(R.id.tab_label);
    planningIndicatorTitle.setText("Planning");
    planningIndicatorTitle.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    ImageView planningIndicatorIcon = (ImageView) planningIndicator.findViewById(R.id.tab_image);
    planningIndicatorIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_calendar);

    switch(mTabHost.getCurrentTab()){
        case 0: 
            werkplekIndicator.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_3d_tab_first_selected);
            werkplekIndicatorIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_werkplek_selected);
            werkplekIndicatorTitle.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.vmt_black));
        break;
        case 1: 
            transportIndicator.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_3d_tab_middle_selected);
            transportIndicatorIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_transport_selected);
            transportIndicatorTitle.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.vmt_black));
        break;
        case 2: 
            inkomendIndicator.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_3d_tab_middle_selected);
            inkomendIndicatorIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_inkomend_selected);
            inkomendIndicatorTitle.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.vmt_black));
        break;
        case 3: 
            zoekenIndicator.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_3d_tab_middle_selected);
            zoekenIndicatorIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_zoeken_selected);
            zoekenIndicatorTitle.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.vmt_black));
        break;
        default: 
            planningIndicator.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_3d_tab_last_selected);
            planningIndicatorIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_calendar_selected);
            planningIndicatorTitle.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.vmt_black));
    }
}
```

The biggest problem is the black bar on top (and in the right bottom corner). I know the code can be a lot shorter but this was just as test. The button backgrounds are all done with 9patches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot explain the solution but I have found it. My suspicion is that the Samsung layer on top of Android does something with the Android Support Library (or doesn't support it the way it should, the irony).

The solution was setting a transparant background to the TabWidget:

```
<TabWidget
      android:id="@+id/tabs"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Define Alternate Layout for your 10 inch tab that is the best one can do.

Comment: The 9patches should scale with any device size. That's the whole point of them. I would've created the same layout xml for the 10 inch version.